# How to convert this text file into panda tables to make plots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, text-files

Here is an image of the text file:

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images, post plain text data and update your post with the code you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and some parameters:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=3, header=None, sep='\s+', comment=',', 
                 names=['z', 'tz', 'tL', 'DA', 'DL'])
print(df)

# Output
       z    tz   tL     DA     DL
0  0.001  13.3  0.1   42.3   43.2
1  0.100  12.2  1.3  380.4  460.3
```

Content of `data.csv`:

```
;###
Omegavac
;;;;
0.001 13.3  0.1 42.3  43.2,,,,
0.1 12.2  1.3 380.4 460.3,,,,
```